# Show individual horizontal lines in a word table

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to show the horizontal lines for specific rows in a table in Apache-POI. Using the table I can show all the horizontal lines but when I go to specific rows I cannot see how to do it. I use getTable but then it applies to the whole table again :(

Can anyone help me with this please?

```
        XWPFTableRow tableRow = table.createRow();
        tableRow.getTable().setInsideHBorder(XWPFBorderType.SINGLE,10, 5,    "1C7331");

        for (int col=0; col<3; col++){
            tableCell = tableRow.getCell(col);
            tableCell.removeParagraph(0);
            textCell = tableCell.addParagraph();
            textCell.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
            textCell.setIndentFromLeft(50);
            run= textCell.createRun();
            run.setBold(true);
            switch(col){
                case 0: run.setText(plantingDate);
                        break;
                case 1: run.setBold(false);
                        run.setText(sampleName);
                        break;
                case 2: run.setBold(false);
                        run.setText(sample.getCount());
                        break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure which lines you want to draw, but a typical way to add a border to a cell is

```
textCell.setBorderBottom(Borders.NONE);
```

for no line and - for example -

```
textCell.setBorderBottom(Borders.BASIC_WIDE_MIDLINE);
```

for a line.

You can also set left and right borders like that. Does this help?

Comment: Border is what I meant :) It doesn't create a solid line for the whole row but I don't mind, It works for me! Thanks!